# Error while running RemoteDesktop commandlets in powershell from C#

Tags: c#, powershell, remote-desktop, remoteapp

I have tried executing RemoteDesktop commandlets in powershell using C#.

The following is my program :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var powershell = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                powershell.Commands.AddCommand("Import-Module").AddArgument("remotedesktop");
                powershell.Invoke();
                powershell.Commands.Clear();
                powershell.AddCommand(@"Get-RDRemoteApp");
                powershell.AddCommand(@"out-string");
                foreach (var result in powershell.Invoke())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(result);
                }
            }
        }
```

When I invoke command it gives the error `System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The term 'Get-RDRemoteApp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

How can I achieve calling RemoteDesktop commandlets ?

I solved this. I change run mode to x64 from Any CPU.

Comment: Is this module installed and available for the user you run the C# code in? You may try importing the module using its complete path to the folder containing the module.

Comment: Yes, This module is installed. When I import this module using powershell console, No error reported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a persistent runspace for all of your commands. The way your code is now, each command is being executed in it's own isolated runspace. Adding the following code:

```
var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.Open();
powershell.Runspace = runspace;
```

to the beginning of the `using` block should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and found your post.

Default `InitialSessionState` only loads Core commandlets and `ExecutionPolicy` is set to the most restrictive: `Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy.Default`.

To work around this, I had to set the `ExecutionPolicy` as shown below :

```cs
InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
iss.ExecutionPolicy = Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy.Bypass;
iss.ImportPSModule("RemoteDesktop");

PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create(iss);
...
```